# Responsive HTML for border around logo image

Tags: html, css

I need to make responsive layout of the design attached , please help.

Things to keep in mind:

1. Can't fix height/width of logo image or any of the div's, it has to be dynamic
2. 5px padding between the border line and the image.

[image]
Thanks!

```css
.width100per {
  max-width:1100px;
  width:100%;
  height:1000px;
  text-align:center;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background-color: #808080;
}

.container { 
  width:100%;
  float:left;
}

.container::after {
  content: " ";
  border-bottom:red 2px solid;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 24%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}


header {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

header .logo {
  float:left;
  width:20%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#000;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
}

header .logo img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="width100per">
  <div class="container"></div>
    <header>
      <div class="logo">
          <img src="jessicarose.nordicfinest.com/static/home_333333.png">
      </div>
    </header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your css

```
header:after{
    content: " ";
    border-bottom: red 2px solid;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}

header{
position:relative;
}
.container::after {
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Please refer to the image, I need the border to be throughout the screen

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="width100per">
      <header>
          <div class="logo">
              <img src="jessicarose.nordicfinest.com/static/home_333333.png">
          </div>
      </header>
    </div>

    /* Css  */

header {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 20%;
  position: relative;
}

header .logo {
  float:left;
  width:20%;
  height:calc(100% + 10px);
  height:-moz-calc(100% + 10px);
  height:-webkit-calc(100% + 10px);
  background-color:#000;
  position: absolute;
  background-color:#000;
  padding: 5px;
  z-index: 20;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
header .logo img{
  padding-top: 20px;
  display:inline-block;     
  float: none;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I dont need the border below the header rather I want it to be at right angled to logo image on left and right both
PLEASE SEE THE IMAGE ATTACHED FOR DESIGN REFERENCE

Comment: I have updated my answer 
Please see, if this works...
you can add border to logo...
or header whatever you want.

Comment: I am confused, can you attach the whole code snippet ?

Comment: I am not on js fiddle...
yet to register,,,

Comment: Have you placed border? surprisingly I cant see any similarity between you code and the design I have attached

Comment: please refer the design first

Comment: Oh! Pardon!!
Actually 
The code was not saved,,,
Its my mistake....
See once again...
http://jsfiddle.net/Gaurav__work/trwk47a0/21/